# How to extract multidimensional associative array to simple numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Here is a code sample

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1197
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1078
        )
)
```

I want it to convert into simple index array as:

```
Array( 1197, 1078 )
```

I know it can be done by iterating each index and assigning into a temp array. I want a one liner syntax like `array_filter` do in many cases. Is there any built-in function in PHP which do my task in one line, any mix of statement in one line. I don't want to use it in loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: `array_column($arr, 'ID');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP > 5.5.0, you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

`$ids = array_column($array, 'ID');`

On the linked page, you'll find a substitute for older versions:

```
if(!function_exists("array_column"))
{

    function array_column($array,$column_name)
    {

        return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return $element[$column_name];}, $array);

    }

}
```